# Using plotselected event with .live() method

Tags: jquery, flot

How to make an event 'plotselected' with .live() method(I can not use bind because the plot is dynamic).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

   jQuery("#placeholder").live("plotclick", function(event, ranges){
         alert("plot click works!");
    }); 

     jQuery("#placeholder").live("plotselected", function(event, ranges){
         alert("plot selected work!");
    }); 
});
```

the plotselected does not work.

Comment: Do you have custom events called "plotclick" and "plotselected"?

Comment: `.live()` is also deprecated as of 1.7

Comment: Johan-> what do you mean? how can I do that? plotclick works, but plotselected does not work. I have not defined a event plotclick

Comment: tymeJV->I know but I do not have another way to use it

Comment: Im trying to use the event in flot libraries like this example: http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/zooming.html, where i need to apply the method:     $("#overview").bind("plotselected", function (event, ranges) {
        plot.setSelection(ranges);
    });, in dynamic plot the method bind does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `plotselected` event to work, you need a couple things:

**Include the selection plugin after flot:**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.7/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.7/jquery.flot.selection.min.js"></script>
```

**Set your options correctly:**

```
var flot = $.plot('#placeholder', [{
    data: [
        [1, 1],
        [2, 3],
        [4, 4],
        [5, 9]
    ],
    //etc
}], {
    selection: {
        mode:'x'
    }
});
```

**Create an event:**

```
$('#placeholder').on('plotselected',function(event,ranges){
   alert('hi'); 
});
```

I saw your question before the edit, and I think you may have been incorrectly specifying the flot options, such that the key `selection` wasn't being properly set for flot.

Here's a working example to help you track down the issue:   http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/8zqyP/

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to include the lib selection. with .live() it works.